# Solution of heat equation is odd

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the heat equation $$v_\xi=v_{\eta\eta},\qquad\eta\in[-L,L]$$ satisfying $v(-L,\xi)=v(L,\xi)$, $v_\eta(-L,\xi)=v_\eta(L,\xi)$ and $v(\eta,0)=g(\eta)$, $g$ odd.

Show that $v$ is odd.

---

I tried to solve the problem in terms of the arbitrary function $g$ and then show that $-v(-\eta,\xi)=v(\eta,\xi)$ by substituting in $-\eta$ into the formula for $v(\eta,\xi)$. Is there a short way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some "niceness" conditions on $g$ are needed, e.g. continuity (or more generally Lebesgue integrability), else solutions might not exist at all.

Consider the map $w \to T(w)$ of functions of two variables, where $T(w)(\eta,\xi) = w(-\eta,\xi)$.  If $u$ is a solution of your PDE, then so is $v = T(u)$.
If $u$ is a solution satisfying your initial and boundary conditions, then so is
$v$.  But since the solution for given initial and boundary conditions is 
unique, we must have $u=v$.